# Массив дат в PHP

Tags: php

Как можно сделать массив из существующих дат? Мне нужен массив с датами с месяца сентебря по май, желательно без выходных. За 2011-2012

Comment: А подробнее можно? Что вы хотите реализовать? В каком виде даты в массиве должны быть?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$start = strtotime('09/01/2010');

$finish = strtotime('05/31/2011');

$arrayOfDates = array();
  for($i=$start; $i<$finish; $i+=86400){
  list($year,$month,$day) = explode("|",date("Y|m|d",$i));
  $arrayOfDates[$year][$month][] = $day;
}
print_r($arrayOfDates);
```

P.S. [`date`](http://ru.php.net/manual/ru/function.date.php) может указать день недели.

```
if(date('D',$i)!='Sun' && date('D',$i)!='Sat');
```

Такое условие в цикле исключит выходные.

Comment: Можно и в диапазоне

Comment: knes, а как можно сделать это в диапозонах по неделям?

Comment: приведите маленький кусочек желаемого массива, я вам скажу как его реализовать

Comment: А можно или агент или icq или skype? А в общем у меня будет страница, где будут отображаться 6 дней с сентебря.

Comment: Если это будет календарь, массив всех дат категорически не нужен. Стоит использовать то, что я написал, но ограничить диапазон месяцем или тремя.

Comment: Нет это будет по тиму дневника школьника