# Календарь и вывод дня недели PHP

Tags: jquery, php

Я взял этот календарь.

[image: календарь]

И сделал 2 инпута с выбором диапазона дат. У меня есть код, который делает этот диапазон

```
$d1 = date('d.m', strtotime($_POST["date1"]));
$d2 = date('d.m', strtotime($_POST["date2"]));
$dates = range($d1,$d2);
```

Теперь мне нужно, чтобы он вывел, какой это день недели.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$dayweek  = array(
"0"=>"Воскресенье" ,
"1"=>"Понедельник" , 
"2"=>"Вторник" ,
"3"=>"Среда" ,
"4"=>"Четверг" ,
"5"=>"Пятница" , 
"6"=>"Суббота" );

echo( $dayweek[date("w", strtotime($_POST["date1"]))]);
```

можно ещё 
    date('D');

Но там нужно писать локаль, что-то типа

```
setlocale ( LC_TIME , 'Russian_Russia.1251' );
```

Answer (score 1):

В вашем варианте будет работать, если ниже дописать:

```
$wdRu = Array('Воскресенье','Понедельник','Вторник','Среда','Четверг','Пятница','Суббота');
for ($i=0;$i<sizeof($dates);$i++) {
  $weekDay[$i] = date('w',strtotime(str_replace(',','.',$dates[$i]).'.11'));
  $out .= $wdRu[$weekDay[$i]].' '.$dates[$i].' ';
}
```

При таком подходе можно использовать конструкцию

```
$wdRu[$weekDay[$i]]
```

для вывода русского названия дня недели, в вашем цикле, там где вам нужно, т.к. у него итератор будет равен итератору в $dates

PS: Кстати ваш подход будет работать только на этот год, т.к. в $dates записываются числа 24,09; 25,09 и т.д.

PPS: вот эту тему гляньте [Массив дат в PHP](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/35635/%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82-%D0%B2-php)