# Массив дат в PHP

Tags: php

Вот тут мне ответили: [массив дат в PHP](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/35635/%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82-%D0%B2-php). Только 1 вопрос: почему при выборе конечной даты

```
$finish = strtotime('05/31/2011');
```

он не выводит ее саму, как ее вывести?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я ступил. Просто надо было сделать

```
$i<=$finish
```